# solution for large amount of time series data with many attributes

Tags: nlp, time-series, bigdata

I am working on a news analytics project, we retrieve events from real time news streams and do sentiment for certain financial instruments. Currently we only generate one time series sentiment stream per instrument, which is aggregated from over 100 types of events and many news website.We use Postgres to store the structured data, pre-calculate/aggregate sentiment and store on Influx to support real time streaming on frontend.

We are thinking of expanding the functionality to let user to be able to select the in scope event types and news sources, so every user can have different sentiment streams. And user should be able to further break down sentiment with only certain event type or source. The ideal solution should be able to let user to define the scope and receive aggregated sentiment on the fly.

I hardly imagine aggregation can be done completely on the fly without any pre-calculation. On the other hand, the most atomic time series is per event type per news source. But in this way we need to maintain (100event types * 100 news source * 1000 instruments) 10million series? Increasing news source further will make the system impossible to maintain.

Can someone please share some thoughts what architecture or technical solution may support our requirements?

Comment: What is sentiment, in CS terms?

Answer (score 0):

If all event types and sources share same instruments, then you can create a one stream and make event type and source a attribute in the stream ( series). Then you can filter the stream by attributes as needed.

However, if different sources have different instruments and event types, then you can have a stream ( time series) for instrument and add source and event type as attributes to each stream so you can filter by attributes.

In general, try to reduce number of streams and encode that information as attributes.

Comment: Thank you! By any chance you know what kind of database can support such large amount of data and filter by many attributes on the fly? We are using InfluxDB to store time series data but it can only filter on timestamp. And I don't think Postgres can do a better job.